# javaFx printing api resolution inappropriate

Tags: java, javafx

I am using the following code for printing a node but i am not getting correct format. i have also set the height and width of the node same as A4 size.

Code is as follows:

```
Printer printer = Printer.getDefaultPrinter();
        PageLayout pageLayout
            = printer.createPageLayout(Paper.A4, PageOrientation.PORTRAIT, Printer.MarginType.HARDWARE_MINIMUM);
        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();

         node.setPrefSize(pageLayout.getPrintableWidth(), pageLayout.getPrintableHeight());
        if (job != null && job.showPrintDialog(node.getScene().getWindow())) {
          boolean success = job.printPage(pageLayout, node);
          if (success) {
            job.endJob();
          }
        }
```

Output should be :
[Desired Outpu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Gvcp.png)

But output getting:
[real output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYYPu.png)

Thankyou in Advance